# Adding up the length of strings in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, iteration

So I am at learning how to do fairly basic things in JavaScript, and I am getting it perfectly, but there is one section that has stumped me:

So I have an

Comment: please add **your** try.

Comment: Seeing no code whatsoever as in no attempt. "New to javascript" does not (for me) add sympathy. Winging it thru school on SO solutions might sound like ideal but what about "test time"? Lost?

Comment: My attempt was: for **(var friend of friends) {
                                       console.log(friend.length);
                                    }**
This does give me the length of each name in the array, but I am just drawing blanks on adding them into count. I keep trying to do count = friend[i].length; but it isn't working. And no, I am not winging it. I didn't know me asking for help was me winging University.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you should try yourself but just to give you a head start, below is the way or structure of the task. Its half way done so i believe you can take it from here. Try it yourself and let me know if you need any help!

```
var friends = ["Benjamin", "Lily", "Emily", " Gabriel"];
var count =0;

for(let i = 0; i <friends.length;i++){
  friends[i].length; //=========> this will display the length of each character    
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Hmmmm... you infer much. Helps tho im sure. The inference is OP even knows how to write a loop.